# Use of permutations and combinations for a conditional seating arrangement

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I've got a problem where there are 6 seats in a row, with 6 people to be seated. I need to figure out all possible seating arrangements, given that two people are married and are to be seated next to each other.

Unless I am mistaken, a full seating arrangement list without any conditions would simply be 6! = 720 possible ways of seating everyone (this equates to a permutation of 6 choosing 6, or 6!/(6-6)!).

However, with two specific people out of the 6 needing to be next to each other, that would make for 10 possible places these two could be seated in the row. I can do this by basic counting of spaces (draw out an array of squares and counting the forward and reverse possibilities of adjacent pairs in the set), but my first problem here is I cannot see a logical calculation for this from the given conditions. I'd expect it to be some sort of permutation of two out of the six spaces, but for that I get 6!/(6-2)! = 30, which is the ways of seating any two people out of 6 chosen and not just the couple...so that's not the proper approach. Using a permutation of n=2 also does not work, and does not seem logical.

After this issue, my approach is to multiply this "10" value into the possible placements for the remaining people, which I'd expect to be 4!, given that there are four people and four spaces in which to put them, so as with the full arrangement list, this would be 4!/(4-4)! = 24.

This gives me 10*4! = 240 possible ways of seating everyone; however, this is not the right answer (the correct answer is 48).

Comment: Isn't $480$ the correct answer? There are not $10$ but $10\times2$ possibilities for the couple: MF or FM $10$ times.

Comment: The 10 count accounts for the swapping of positions for the two. Given places 1 through 6, we would have 12,21,23,32,34,43,45,54,56,65 which are 10 possibilities.

Comment: I misread your question and thought that the couple should *not* sit next to eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have persons $a,b,c,d,e,f$ with persons $a$ and $b$ being married and needing to sit next to one another (and no other married couples needing to be sat together).  We want to count the number of ways these six people can be sat along a row (with a distinct start and end)

For the moment, denote the married couple $a,b$ as a single entity: $X$.  How many ways do we have to arrange $X,c,d,e,f$ in a row?  (e.g. one such outcome could look like $cXefd$)

> $5! = 120$

Now that we have arranged the "five", replace $X$ with $a$ and $b$ again, but decide how to arrange $a$ and $b$ when putting it back in.  (e.g. from $cXefd$ we now make it either $cabefd$ or $cbaefd$)

> either $a$ is on the left or on the right: two possibilities.

By multiplication principle, the total number of arrangements is the multiplication of the number of choices at each of these two steps for a total of:

> $5!\cdot 2 = 120\cdot 2 = 240$

---

If instead there are multiple married couples, each of which need to sit next to eachother then do similarly.  Suppose $a$ and $b$ are married and need to sit next to eachother, $c$ and $d$ are married and need to sit next to eachother, and $e$ and $f$ are married and need to sit next to eachother.

For the moment, treat $a$ and $b$ as one collective entity: $X$.  treat $c$ and $d$ as one collective entity: $Y$.  treat $e$ and $f$ as one collective entity: $Z$.

How many ways are there to arrange $X,Y,Z$?  (e.g. $YXZ$)

> $3!$

Replacing $X$ with $a$ and $b$, how many ways can you do that? (e.g. $YbaZ$)

> $2$

Replacing $Y$ with $c$ and $d$, how many ways can you do that? (e.g. $cdbaZ$)

> $2$

Similarly, replace $Z$ with $e$ and $f$, in how many ways? (e.g. $cdbaef$)

> $2$

By multiplication principle, multiply the number of ways of accomplishing each step for a total of:

> $3! \cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2 = 8\cdot 6 = 48$

Given your statement in your post that this was the answer you expected, it appears that this was the interpretation and that you had neglected to mention that there are **multiple** married couples, all of which must sit near one another.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed and step-by-step response. I love the hidden answers that only show when you hover over it...allowed me to critically think about each step without bias. However, the problem is specifically the following: "In how many ways can six people sit in six seats in a line at a movie? How does this change with the condition that one of the six people, Jane, is married to Joe and must sit next to him?" The answer in my book for this question is 48....perhaps there's an error, but as with most books, there's no explanation, and this is bugging me big-time!

Comment: @Topher If it was worded exactly as that, then it would fall into the first interpretation above and have 240 possibilities.  There have been known to be mistakes in books where they thought they asked one question but in fact had asked something different.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the couple as a unity there are $5!$ arrangements. Realizing that there are also $2$ arrangements for the couple itself (man at left side or at right side of the woman) we come to a total of $2\times5!$ arrangements.

---

If it concerns $3$ couples that must sit next to eachother then there are $3$ units hence $3!$ arrangements if we only look at these units. Again for every unit there are $2$ arrangements (man left or right) leading to a total of $2\times2\times2\times3!=48$ arrangements.

Comment: Thanks! The logic here makes sense. I wasnt sure how to best treat the couple in the argument, and it makes sense to lump them as one of 5 items, instead of individually among 6. As for the answer, its still confusing to me since 48 is the answer in the book (I replied to the other answer with the problem's specific wording). My guess here is that the book is mistaken.

Comment: Glad to help. It is beyond any doubt that the book is wrong (and you are right) if there is only such a restriction for *one* couple.